# Calendar event times a mess when in travel

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, ios, macos-sierra, icloud

how to make the calendar times to work worldwide? I use  Calendar on all my devices but when I travel the times turns to a mess.
For example, a flight from A to B is always set as the local time of departure in the city A and the arrival time is the local time in the city B, Before your suggesting. 
I will explain what I already tried:

1 - I tried to use times as suggested in the email I receive from the airline companies, it shows departure and arrival as local time in the cities.
2 - I tried to use times as in my local time like departure is city A time and arrival is city A time.
3 - I tried to use UTC times for departure and arrivals.
4 - I tried to turn On/Off the Time Zone Support in Calendar, iPhone, iPad and iCloud Web site.
5 - I tried all combinations of the 3 steps above.

It is very weird because sometimes you can set all times correct change your time zone in the devices and everything seems to work perfect but as soon as you land in the destination the hours are completely wrong again.

I understand I can include in the header of the event or in the event text the correct times but this is not the way it should work. I went to visit an apple store and the person said the calendar is to be used in local times in your local city it was not developed for travelers.  I don't believe that.

Anyway would be nice to have an input of someone who travels and not speculations on how it should work.

I am not trying to be rude but I am in this search for longtime and got nowhere.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Apple Care guy is probably right, there's not much you can do in Calendar app with iCloud or Local calendars, as it's using system time value for all calendars.

Not travelling much, though I know Google Calendars have timezone value event-wise so you could add two events: arrival time and departure time each assigned to the needed timezone. You can simply log in Google account in Accounts in settings and it will sync automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that logging in at the new destination changes the time **zone** of your device and not only the time itself? Maybe the manual setting of the time zone before arriving at the destination leads to a wrong time zone detection.

I used to have the problem that my device did recognize e.g. the new network it was on and changed the displayed time but in settings it was still set to my local time zone which led to problems like the ones you have.